# Retrieve the value of the checkbox in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to retrieve the value of the checkbox on kivy to write some logic. Could someone please help me and tell me where i can find such information in kivy's documentation as i was left with little luck.

here is the code.

Python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class Tab(TabbedPanel):

    check = ObjectProperty(False)

    def btn(self):

        print(self.check)


class Checkbox(CheckBox):
    pass


filekv = Builder.load_file("GUI.kv")


class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return filekv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

Kv file:

```
<TextInput>:
    multiline:False

Tab:

    do_default_tab: False
    check:checked

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Test Request'

        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            spacing: 20
            padding: 20

            Label:
                text: "Sample ID: "

            TextInput:
                id: id_sample

            Checkbox:
            #how do i retrieve the value of the checkbox here??

            Label:
                text: ""

            Button:
                text: "Submit"
                on_press: root.btn()
```

I tried using:

```
id: checked
active: checked
value: checked
```

But nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to give an `id` to the `Checkbox`:

```
            Checkbox:
                id: check_box
```

... and then you have its state like this:
`print(self.ids.check_box.state)`

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much! Where can i find such information? I tried the Kivy documentation here but i didn't quite find what i was looking for. https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.checkbox.html